# Check if we're viewing an event

Tags: plugins, theme-development, the-events-calendar

I need to know how to check if the user is looking at an event or the list of events from the plugin The Events Calendar on my custom theme's page.php.

One solution I thought of was to grab the url. mysite.com/events shows the list of events, and mysite.com/event/theevent shows a specific event. I thought about grabbing the permalink using `get_the_permalink()` / `get_permalink()` and checking if it contains event/events, but that doesn't seem to be returning anything for me while on an events page.

Or if I could set the category (the actual wordpress category, not the calendar category) to something like "events" I could use has_category('events'), but I don't know how to do that..

Any suggestions?

---

Edit:

I went snooping around in The Event Calendar's php files and found [`tribe_is_event()`](https://theeventscalendar.com/function/tribe_is_event/) and I'm able to determine if the page is an event, but only **after** `the_content()` has been called. I need to know *before* that happens.

Comment: Are the events a custom post type?

Comment: Sorry, I guess i forgot to mention im using The Events Calendar plugin. Edited.

Comment: Ah. Do they have support?

Comment: They have a list of functions, but I haven't found anything useful yet, and when I think I have it's deprecated. https://theeventscalendar.com/functions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the post id outside the loop with `$wp_query` and then feed it to `tribe_is_event()`. works a treat.

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
if (tribe_is_event($wp_query->post->ID)) {echo "yup"; } else {echo "nah"; }
?>
```